# using pencil with 1 pixel in GIMP has no effect cannot draw on any layer

Tags: gimp

I wanted to start trying to make some pixel art characters. I tried 128x128 and even 16x16 image.

I have grid enabled and snap to grid enabled (even though the cursor doesn't appear to snap to the grid unless I hold shift which seems to be a line-tool)

Regardless of this, no matter what I do the pixel doesnt draw. If I change brush and size to 3 then I get a 'cross' consisting of 5 pixels.

Here is a screenshot of my problem, the cursor is not snapped and the settings are shown for the pencil, which will not draw

[image]

Comment: Uncheck "Lock brush to view" in the Tool options.

Comment: @billykerr You should post that as an answer. And feel free to augment it with parts of my own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on @BillKerr comment, "Lock brush to view" scales the brush with the zoom: the ratio `brush size/window area` remains constant, so that at high zoom factors you don't get a brush that is bigger than your image window. In effect this shrinks the brush as you zoom in. If course if you start with a 3px brush, at 3800% zoom it is 3/38=0.1 pixel and is inoperative.

Further more, the `1. Pixel` brush is "parametric". Gimp has two kinds of brushes:

- "parametric" brushes (`.vbr` files), that are simple shapes defined by a few parameters: shape (circle/square/diamond), radius, and sides. These are the ones that you can edit with the brush editor. Under the hood they are close to vector graphics.
- "bitmap" brushes, that are plain bitmap images (the `z. Pepper` brush, for instance)(`.gbr` files)

So, when you look closely, the `1. Pixel` brush will always be at least 3px (one pixel for center, and 2x1 pixels due to radius=1. If you want a real 1-pixel brush, it has to be a bitmap brush. Gimp comes with such a brush, called **`Pixel (1x1 square)`**.

Comment: A brush like this exists among the default brushes, only further down in the list.

Comment: @xenoid Sorry I was away when you left a comment, but anyway I don't think I could improve on your answer.

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher OK fixed.

Comment: thank you for the help all. I didn't even notice or think about that option, maybe i clicked it by mistake or it was on by default. Thanks!!